# Behaviour of sting.match()

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am a little confused by the behaviour of the `match` method on javascripts `string` type.

I have a string containing:

```
<num> Number: 401 
<title> foreign minorities, Germany
```

Now I want to parse `401` out of it using this regex:

```
/(Number: )(\d+)/g
```

This should give me two groups whereas the seconds should contain 401.

Trying this in node.js with this code:

```
const r_num = /Number: (\d+)/g;
let str = `<num> Number: 401 
    <title> foreign minorities, Germany `;
let res = str.match(r_num);
```

I am however only getting one element in my result array containing the full match rather then the two groups.

So how can I get groups rather then the full match in my result array?